# CodePlex integration bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I just added one of my [CodePlex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex) projects to [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers). During that process I got the following message:

> The application ApplicationName wants to confirm your identity.

Shouldn't `ApplicationName` be *Stack Overflow Careers*?

Comment: Thanks! We’ve passed that on to our friends over at CodePlex. Looks like it functions OK though.

Comment: ok. it was a 50-50 chance. You either didn't provide an application name, or they didn't use it. Guess I made the wrong bet ;) Pekka, do some trolling please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodePlex guys have updated it, should be good.